# When starting sonar, I get the following exception: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available

Tags: java, macos, elasticsearch, sonarqube

When starting sonar (sonar start) I get this exception:

```
2015.05.11 15:19:15 INFO  web[o.s.c.p.Database]  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2015.05.11 15:19:16 WARN  web[o.s.s.d.DatabaseChecker]  H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
2015.05.11 15:19:16 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem]  SonarQube home: /usr/local/Cellar/sonar4/4.5.4/libexec
2015.05.11 15:19:45 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase]  Embedded database stopped
2015.05.11 15:19:45 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]]  Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:219) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportIndicesAdminClient.execute(InternalTransportIndicesAdminClient.java:85) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractIndicesAdminClient.exists(AbstractIndicesAdminClient.java:164) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.exists.indices.IndicesExistsRequestBuilder.doExecute(IndicesExistsRequestBuilder.java:54) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.search.BaseIndex.initializeIndex(BaseIndex.java:155) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.search.BaseIndex.start(BaseIndex.java:98) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
```

I have tried this with sonar 4 and sonar 5 on a mac os 10.10, jdk 1.8. I used brew to install sonar (brew install sonar/ brew install sonar4) and I have tried to install it using
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled the firewall and it seems to be working now.